# How to remove CSS classes using JQ

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to remove CSS using by button id. I tried out this code but its not working. Can someone help me how to do it?

```
<button id="QF_1_Y" class="Class1" value="Y" style="display: inline-block;">YES</button>
<button id="QF_1_N" class="Class2" value="N" style="display: inline-block;">NO</button>
<button id="QF_1_NA" class="Class1 Class3 " value="NA" style="display: inline-block;">NA</button>
```

Code :

```
var id1="#QF"+1+"Y";
var id2="#QF"+1+"N";
var id3="#QF"+1+"NA";
$(id1).removeClass('Class1'); 
$(id2).removeClass('Class2');
$(id3).removeClass('Class1 Class3');
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6):

you need to add a "_" like.

```
var id1="#QF_"+1+"_Y";
var id2="#QF_"+1+"_N";
var id3="#QF_"+1+"_NA";
$(id1).removeClass('Class1'); 
$(id2).removeClass('Class2');
$(id3).removeClass('Class1 Class3');
```